# Is there a way to make TLS work with rsyslog in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, tls, rsyslog

I configure rsyslog to load the TLS module (to talk to loggly) and I'm getting this error:

```
Jun 20 13:14:00 feynman rsyslogd-2068: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', rsyslog error -2078
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2068 ]
```

that page, http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2068, says that there should be another error message nearby. At least in /var/log/syslog, this is all I see:

```
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="22276" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole' [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd-2068: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', rsyslog error -2078
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2068 ]
Jun 20 13:17:01 feynman rsyslogd-2068: could not load module '/usr/lib/rsyslog/lmnsd_gtls.so', rsyslog error -2078
 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2068 ]
```

The /dev/xconsole error happens even if I disable TLS and everything seems to be fine. Not sure if I should read anything into it.

Maybe there's another log file to inspect that I'm missing?

Searching I found this bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/869881

From that, it seams that rsyslog tls is just broken on Ubuntu and that's the end of it. No workaround, no fixes coming, nothing. Am I reading it right? Is there any workaround or any other way to move forward?

Answer (score 2):

The [error page for 2078](http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2078), which is mentioned in the error but not the number in the printed link, says:

> This message occurs with TLS netstream driver. For TLS, certificates (.pem files) are needed to provide security credentials. This error is issued if there is a problem with these files. The message contains a more precise error description. That error text is taken directly from the underlying TLS library.
>
> A common cause is that the file can not be found or accessed (permissions!). In that case, a rsyslogd-2040 error will follow.

Further, if you check `/usr/lib/rsyslog/` and `lmnsd_gtls.so` really does not exist, it points at `rsyslog-gnutls` possibly not being installed.

Comment: Installing rsyslog-gnutls fixes this error for me. (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)

Comment: Still true 9 years later on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0):

The last comment suggests removing removing ubuntu-orchestra packages, have you tried that?

From the bug report:

> Following directly on from the previous comment, removing the various ubuntu-orchestra packages causes the 'lmnsd_gtls.so' complaint to disappear:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-orchestra-*
```

The bug report does seem to indicate that this issue has not been patched, however. I assume you've upgraded to the latest rsyslog and gnutls/openssl?

Regarding the xconsole issue, you can get rid of that by commenting out the entire `daemon.*;mail.*;\` block in rsyslog.conf. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/108924/missing-dev-xconsole-causes-rsyslog-to-stop-as-well-as-all-other-services)